# How to convert from Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ListItem to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to convert  Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ListItem to  Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File

I have tried

```
listItem as Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File
```

and

```
(Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File)listItem
```

but none of them work. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ListItem.File` Property to retrieve the file. Like this:

```
File file=listItem.File
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.file?view=sharepoint-csom